# Fastest way to fetch,segregate and write the corresponding data in a file using python and oracle db

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, oracle, file

I've been trying to fetch huge chunks of data from a db only to parse and segregate it and write it into csv files using python. The data is quite huge and so I decided to dump it into a temporary file where I would segregate it and create multiple csv files out of it (I was thinking handling so much data would be exhausting for python and that is why this dumping). Right now, only the writing of data into this temporary file is exceeding the time limits and I'm not able to even start with the segregation part. I'm a beginner here, suggest me the correct way to go about for this.
I can also try segregating immediately after fetching and then straight away writing it into csvs,so if there's some advice on that, it could work well for me
Most of the time is spent on writing the data into the file
EDIT - So by segregation I mean that I have to segregate each and every record based on the value of one column that is being fetched with every record.

```
cur = con.cursor()
file = open("Data_for_2_Days.text","w+")

print("Starting execution of query")
currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()
print("timestamp at the start of execution of query =  ")
print(currentTime)

result  = cur.execute(query)

print("query executed")
currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()
print("time after execution =  ")
print(currentTime)

print("beginning to write")
currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()

for item in result:
    file.write(str(item))

print("finished writing")
currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()
print("time after writing =  ")
print(currentTime)
file.close
```

Comment: why do you have to save to a temp file, why cant you seggregate your data to csv files from `result`. Also have a look at the `Pandas` library if you are dealing with tables

Comment: Can you suggest me a quick way to segregate every record based on the value of a column and based on that value I have to place data in different csv files. Actually the data being fetched is in order and even if I just observe a change in the value of that column I can put it into a different file based on that

Comment: is every changed  value unique?  ie when you `observe a change in the value of that column`, does it change to a new value every time?

Comment: No. Let me put it this way - I'm supposedly dealing with a database that has records of all the individuals of a country. Now I have to segregate based on their city, where a new file will be created for every city. The only difference is that there are only 10 cities and the data that will be fetched will be in order so - let's say I observe a change from New York City to Los Angeles , I know that the next batch of data will be for LA and New York is done, there won't be any more of New York.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, do you know where are you spending most of the time: executing the query, fetching data or writing to the file? If fetching data, then try setting the cursor's arraysize, for example:

```
cur.arraysize=1000
```

This should improve fetch times.
That being said, I'm not sure that this is the best way to do what you said your trying to do. What exactly do you mean by segregation?

Comment: Most of  the time is spent in writing the data into the file.

Comment: So by segregation I mean that I have to segregate each and every record based on the value of one column that is being fetched with every record.

Comment: If, as you said, most of the time is spent in writing the file, then you may be better to have the same code fetch part of the data (using some predicate in the where clause), start several instances of the process each writing it's part to a different file. That is, do this if your I/O subsystem allows for a larger bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

If you read your data to a pandas dataframe, then make use of [pandas.Series.unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) to get the unique values of a column and the use [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to save to csv files

```
df  = #read the data to a dataframe named df
```

let `cities` be the name of the column,

```
for city in df['cities'].unique():
    df[df['cities'] == city].to_csv('/path_to_folder/{}.csv'.format(city), index=False)
```